# MYSQL Concat not working

Tags: mysql, concatenation

> UPDATE profile SET
>   favourties=CONCAT(favourties,"123")
>   WHERE id=1

i want to append 123 in favourties but if default value of favourties is set to NULL then this query will not work. What will be query if favourties is set to NULL and then append 123 with it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE profile SET favourties=CONCAT(IFNULL(favourties, ''),"123") WHERE id=1
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the field around with the [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

```
UPDATE profile
SET favourties = CONCAT(COALESCE(favourties, ''),"123")
WHERE id=1
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't concatenate something to NULL. Maybe you can use `coalesce`?

```
UPDATE profile SET favourties=CONCAT(COALESCE(favourites,""),"123") WHERE id=1
```

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

You can use `ifnull` like @zerkms says, but that is not in the SQL standard. It is a tiny tad faster though. Read up on it at this link: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/performance-isnull-vs-coalesce.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `CONCAT_WS()` ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)) which deals with NULLs as you would expect: converts them to an empty string:

```
UPDATE profile SET favourties = CONCAT_WS('', favourties, "123") WHERE id = 1;
```

I personally actually only use `CONCAT_WS()` now because having to worry about NULLs annoys me. I rarely use NULLs so I don't have to worry about it, but just incase. It's just an annoying thing to figure out why you you're ending up with an empty string when it just doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, I use:

```
SET `trans`=concat('$var', trans)
```

to add to a string already in the `trans` column.
It wouldn't work on column named `group` without using back ticked `group` inside the brackets as well, whereas with trans, back ticks were not needed.